# Does Rust have an equivalent of Python's threading.Timer?

Tags: timer, rust

I'm looking for a timer which uses threads, not plain `time.sleep`:

```py
from threading import Timer

def x():
    print "hello"
    t = Timer(2.0, x)
    t.start()

t = Timer(2.0, x)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [timer](https://crates.io/crates/timer) crate

```
extern crate timer;
extern crate chrono;

use timer::Timer;
use chrono::Duration;
use std::thread;

fn x() {
    println!("hello");
}

fn main() {
    let timer = Timer::new();
    let guard = timer.schedule_repeating(Duration::seconds(2), x);
    // give some time so we can see hello printed
    // you can execute any code here
    thread::sleep(::std::time::Duration::new(10, 0));
    // stop repeating
    drop(guard);
}
```

Comment: Could you use this to update a field in a mutable struct?

Comment: @lsund If you mean whether or not it's possible to leave a mutable reference in the closure accessible from elsewhere, from the crate's source it looks like the answer is 'no' barring a `Mutex`'d or `Arc`'d etc. ref to a `Cell`-and-friends global (or `unsafe` code).

Comment: (and then there are [channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) and [scoped_tls](https://github.com/alexcrichton/scoped-tls/blob/master/src/lib.rs) and stuff, but in the end you still need to wrap up the object in a `Send`-ly way)

Answer (score 7):

It's easy enough to write a similar version yourself, using only tools from the standard library:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct Timer<F> {
    delay: Duration,
    action: F,
}

impl<F> Timer<F>
where
    F: FnOnce() + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    fn new(delay: Duration, action: F) -> Self {
        Timer { delay, action }
    }

    fn start(self) {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(self.delay);
            (self.action)();
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    fn x() {
        println!("hello");
        let t = Timer::new(Duration::from_secs(2), x);
        t.start();
    }

    let t = Timer::new(Duration::from_secs(2), x);
    t.start();

    // Wait for output
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
}
```

As [pointed out by malbarbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009480/does-rust-have-an-equivalent-of-pythons-threading-timer#comment61578420_37011364), this does create a new thread for each timer. This can be more expensive than a solution which reuses threads but it's a very simple example.

Comment: Note that it can be inefficient to allocate a new thread in each `start` invocation.

Comment: @malbarbo great point! If you want a recurring task, it's **much** better to use the same thread over and over again, which I assume the timer crate from your answer does. I was just trying to match the Python semantics.