# Issue with borrowing while spawning thread inside other thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures, borrowing

I have read the following question:

[How can I run a set of functions on a recurring interval without running the same function at the same time using only the standard Rust library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253623/how-can-i-run-a-set-of-functions-on-a-recurring-interval-without-running-the-sam)

and elaborated some more complex tests.
The following code add a &str parameter for the functions and it works:

```
use std::{
    thread,
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

fn main() {
    let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
        let wait_time = Duration::from_millis(500);

        let one: &str = "Alpha";
        let two: &str = "Beta";

        // Make this an infinite loop
        // Or some control path to exit the loop
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let start = Instant::now();
            eprintln!("Scheduler starting at {:?}", start);

            let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || { a(&one) });
            let thread_b = thread::spawn(move || { b(&two) });

            thread_a.join().expect("Thread A panicked");
            thread_b.join().expect("Thread B panicked");

            let runtime = start.elapsed();

            if let Some(remaining) = wait_time.checked_sub(runtime) {
                eprintln!(
                    "schedule slice has time left over; sleeping for {:?}",
                    remaining
                );
                thread::sleep(remaining);
            }
        }
    });

    scheduler.join().expect("Scheduler panicked");
}

fn a(a: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", a);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100))
}
fn b(b: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", b);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200))
}
```

My understanding is that this works because Copy Trait is implemented for str.
Now consider the following example:

```
use std::{
    thread,
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

fn main() {
    let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
        let wait_time = Duration::from_millis(500);

        let one: String = String::from("Alpha");
        let two: String = String::from("Beta");

        // Make this an infinite loop
        // Or some control path to exit the loop
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let start = Instant::now();
            eprintln!("Scheduler starting at {:?}", start);

            let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || { a(&one) });
            let thread_b = thread::spawn(move || { b(&two) });

            thread_a.join().expect("Thread A panicked");
            thread_b.join().expect("Thread B panicked");

            let runtime = start.elapsed();

            if let Some(remaining) = wait_time.checked_sub(runtime) {
                eprintln!(
                    "schedule slice has time left over; sleeping for {:?}",
                    remaining
                );
                thread::sleep(remaining);
            }
        }
    });

    scheduler.join().expect("Scheduler panicked");
}

fn a(a: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", a);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100))
}
fn b(b: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", b);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200))
}
```

I am getting this at compile time:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `one`
  --> src\main.rs:19:42
   |
10 |         let one: String = String::from("Alpha");
   |             --- move occurs because `one` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
19 |             let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || { a(&one) });
   |                                          ^^^^^^^      --- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                                          |
   |                                          value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `two`
  --> src\main.rs:20:42
   |
11 |         let two: String = String::from("Beta");
   |             --- move occurs because `two` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
20 |             let thread_b = thread::spawn(move || { b(&two) });
   |                                          ^^^^^^^      --- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                                          |
   |                                          value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

**EDIT1**

It seems it can be solved with the use of .clone()
But now consider the following code:

```
use std::{
    thread,
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

fn main() {

    let one: String = String::from("Alpha");
    let two: String = String::from("Beta");

    let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
        let wait_time = Duration::from_millis(500);

        // Make this an infinite loop
        // Or some control path to exit the loop
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let start = Instant::now();
            eprintln!("Scheduler starting at {:?}", start);

            let one = one.clone();
            let two = two.clone();

            let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || { a(&one) });
            let thread_b = thread::spawn(move || { b(&two) });

            thread_a.join().expect("Thread A panicked");
            thread_b.join().expect("Thread B panicked");

            let runtime = start.elapsed();

            if let Some(remaining) = wait_time.checked_sub(runtime) {
                eprintln!(
                    "schedule slice has time left over; sleeping for {:?}",
                    remaining
                );
                thread::sleep(remaining);
            }
        }
    });

    scheduler.join().expect("Scheduler panicked");
}

fn a(a: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", a);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100))
}
fn b(b: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", b);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200))
}
```

I am now getting different error codes:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `two`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:11:35
   |
11 |     let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
   |                                   ^^ may outlive borrowed value `two`
...
21 |             let two = two.clone();
   |                       --- `two` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src\main.rs:11:21
   |
11 |       let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
   |  _____________________^
12 | |         let wait_time = Duration::from_millis(500);
13 | |
14 | |         // Make this an infinite loop
...  |
38 | |         }
39 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `two` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
11 |     let scheduler = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `one`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:11:35
   |
11 |     let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
   |                                   ^^ may outlive borrowed value `one`
...
20 |             let one = one.clone();
   |                       --- `one` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src\main.rs:11:21
   |
11 |       let scheduler = thread::spawn(|| {
   |  _____________________^
12 | |         let wait_time = Duration::from_millis(500);
13 | |
14 | |         // Make this an infinite loop
...  |
38 | |         }
39 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `one` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
11 |     let scheduler = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errorsù
```

Answer (score 4):

For brevity I'll only mention `one`, but the same applies to `two`. The issue with `thread::spawn(move || { a(&one) })` is that `one` is moved into the closure, which then results in the compile error, as `one` is no longer available for the next iteration.

Borrowing `&one` up front won't work either, because the thread borrowing `one` can outlive the outer thread. To get it working you can clone `one` (and `two`) before spawning the threads.

```rust
let one = one.clone();
let two = two.clone();

let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || a(&one));
let thread_b = thread::spawn(move || b(&two));
```

---

Alternatively, if you really want to borrow it, and not clone it. Then you can use, e.g. [`crossbeam`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam) and a scope for spawning threads. *See also ["How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread).*

```rust
...

let one: String = String::from("Alpha");
let two: String = String::from("Beta");

let one = &one;
let two = &two;

crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
    // Make this an infinite loop
    // Or some control path to exit the loop
    for _ in 0..5 {
        let start = Instant::now();
        eprintln!("Scheduler starting at {:?}", start);

        let thread_a = scope.spawn(move |_| a(&one));
        let thread_b = scope.spawn(move |_| b(&two));

        thread_a.join().expect("Thread A panicked");
        thread_b.join().expect("Thread B panicked");

        let runtime = start.elapsed();

        if let Some(remaining) = wait_time.checked_sub(runtime) {
            eprintln!(
                "schedule slice has time left over; sleeping for {:?}",
                remaining
            );
            thread::sleep(remaining);
        }
    }
})
.unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I have added a different version and I am now getting different error messages. How should I fix it in that case?

Comment: That issue can be fixed by adding `move` the the initial closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sharing non-static immutable data among multiple threads, use `Arc`.  That's what it's for.